# How can set android:layout_alignParentRight="true" programmatically for a layout in android in xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin.android, xamarin

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
```

> Not able to use above code in xamarin

Thanks,
Ashik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `params.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentRight);` instead

Comment: thanks! Still got a problem does not params not providing me AddRule method. Do I need to include anything to use the method?

Comment: when you get your params, use the next code `var params = yourView.LayoutParameters as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;` then you will have AddRule method

Answer (score 0):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Aling_layout;
 Aling_layout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(sizeBX , sizeBY);
 Aling_layout.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentLeft);
 button.LayoutParameters = Aling_layout;
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer ?